# Redirect after Firebase Write

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am looking to redirect to another page after a document has been written to firebase, what would be the best way of doing this? At the moment, I have something that looks like this:

```
var scoreRef = firebase.database().ref('scores');
scoreRef.push(myObj).then(() => {

  document.location.href = "index.html";

});
```

I am using push to get a unique Id.

**EDIT:** Is there enough time for it to write to Firebase before it redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using vanilla js than

```
location.href="URL"
  or
location.replace("URL")
  or
location.assign("URL")
```

are the three properties you can use.

Comment: Thanks man! Would my code give enough time to write to firebase before redirecting?

Comment: Writing to firebase won't take much time, Use  .then after writing is completed on firebase to navigate. If you want to make it user responsive you can add a loading in between the writing and redirecting.